# Drupal php page that accepts clean URL arguments

Tags: url, drupal, drupal-6, clean-urls

I am using Drupal 6 and have my own node that is pulling in my custom php page.  The URL is `domain.com/blogs`. I want to use clean URLs for arguments.  For example, `domain.com/blogs/1` will pull in the information from the database regarding the first blog post.

I've tried:

`domain.com/blogs/1` and in the php code use `arg(0)` BUT I never even get to run the code because Drupal comes up with `Page Not Found` error.

Is there any way to let Drupal know that any arguments after `domain.com/blogs` is allowed and to load the node for `/blogs` also sending the args?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliasing `node/1234` to `blogs` doesn't mean you can control the rest of the menu router item.

For an example, if your unaliased node path is "node/1234" , you "own" the rest of the arguments. 
i.e You can access `567` from `node/1234/567` from PHP like this:

```
<?php print arg(2); ?>
```

If you want to "own" `/blogs` URL part, you have to define it using [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_menu/6). As you have already touched php, I think the best way would be making the module. 
You can however use Views or Panels modules for that.

```
<?php
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['blogs'] = array(
    'title' => 'Main Blogs page', 
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_page', 
    'access arguments' => array('access content'), 
    'type' => MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM,
  );
  $items['blogs/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_blog_view', 
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'), 
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}
function MYMODULE_blog_view($blog_id){
// $node = node_load($blog_id);
// return print_r($node, TRUE);
}
?>
```

Now, in MYMODULE_blog_view function, you can get the arguments from arg(1) as well. You can also make it in a single page callback by combining both menu router items but I'd recommend separate router items.

Update( Aug 8 ) :
The reason why I used node_load($blog_id) and other commented junk there is assuming you needed parts from the node (e.g: You want make show a View with the node ID argument, or something similar that needs specific data from the node). 
But ***never*** allow users to view a node loaded from node_load() because it's like god giving whatever the user asks for.

For nodes, let me explain a little gimmic. Put this in the callback function.

```
  $node = node_load($blog_id);
  if ($node && $node->type == 'blog'){
    $_GET['q'] = 'node/' . $node->nid;
    return menu_execute_active_handler('node/' . $node->nid, FALSE);
   }
   drupal_not_found(); // important!
```

This will load the node ID from the blog ID (which is from the URL), check if it's in 'blog' type and sets the menu handler to the relevant node ID path. 
Now, when you access blog/123 , you will see content of node/123 if it's a blog node. But it's not a redirection. It will not work as fully aliased URL but is helpful sometimes.

Alternately you can check if theuser has access to the node from [node_access](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_access/7)().

Comment: thanks for the post, how do I get to load my custom php page that I have in the body section of the node blogs/
This will be the area where I can then render what the page looks like based on arg(1)

Comment: I put in return node_view(node_load($nodeId));
You recommend?

Comment: Please don't. This opens a big security issue that the user has access to any node.
See updated answer for some workarounds. thanks.

Comment: most of the code from updated answer is from comment.module's page callback for comment permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

here some links you can read about Defining and sending Views Arguments
[drupal.org/1](http://drupal.org/node/129532)

[drupal.org/2](http://drupal.org/node/70145)

Comment: I'd rather not use Views, trying to do it without